# ImportError: No module named cv2 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv

Here is what I have done

```
import cv2
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/include/opencv')

im = cv2.imread("im1.png")
print type(im)
```

Then terminal gives me

```
  File "m7.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

It seems to be installed here

```
 pkg-config opencv --cflags
-I/usr/include/opencv  
 whereis opencv
 opencv: /usr/include/opencv /usr/share/opencv
```

List of my files in `build`

```
3rdparty  CMakeCache.txt       cmake_uninstall.cmake    cvconfig.h  include  Makefile  OpenCVConfig.cmake          unix-install
apps      CMakeFiles           CPackConfig.cmake        data        junk     modules   OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  version_string.tmp
bin       cmake_install.cmake  CPackSourceConfig.cmake  doc         lib      opencv2   OpenCVModules.cmake
```

Comment: Looks like you missed step 8 
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Comment: @matcheek Exists cmake gui on Ubuntu,yes or now?

Comment: `apt-get install cmake`
if not covered by
`apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  adding the path before you try to import the cv modules.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/include/opencv')
import cv2
```

Regards

Comment: have you tried importing opencv instead of cv2? Look into the install folders and try to find the correct module name.

Comment: Yes,but same problems again.

Comment: Did you have a look at  matcheek's suggestion?

Comment: I am not sure if there is cmake gui on Ubuntu,may be I am wrong.